# High speed UDP receiver in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, udp, ethernet

I'd like to implement the receiving end of my system in MATLAB - this requires Gigabit Ethernet with sustained speeds of over 200Mb/sec.

Using MATLAB's built-in [UDP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/instrument/udp.html) from the [Instrument Control Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/instrument/) does not appear to be sufficient. Are there any good alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know Java, you can write the networking part of your code in Java classes, load those into your Matlab session with javaclasspath(), and invoke them from M-code. This could transform the problem from getting the data through Matlab's udp() function to getting the data across the Java/Matlab boundary.

Answer (score 0):

If the data can be put into batches:

Use an external program to download the data to your computer, and save it to a file. Then, Matlab can read from that file whenever it needs more data. That way you partition the problem into two manageable pieces - and if you're using a decent OS, the file will never leave RAM so you won't have to worry about speed.

Answer (score 0):

Theres an very good Example for the Java UDP implementation on the Mathworks site.
(Link below)

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24525-a-simple-udp-communications-application/content/judp.m