# How to play a live UDP video stream in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, udp, video-streaming

I'm coding a MATLAB script that takes a live video stream on a port and plays that video in a MATLAB gui. I've looked at the videoinput function, but that seems to require actual hardware connected to the computer.

I'm listening for a UDP video stream on a certain port, and I'd like to play this video in pseudo-realtime in a GUI. Currently I'm receiving the raw RGB bytestream frame-by-frame.

To the point:

Is this possible?
If so, how would one go about doing this? At this point, any solution would be feasible, although I'd like to use built-in functions for most of the work.

Comment: You need to be specific of what kind of video format and what protocol over UDP you are listening to. If your video is raw RGB and each UDP packet would contain the entire frame, please say so explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need high throughput, you can easily interface Matlab to a UDP port with the [UDP toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/instrument/udp.html).

If your frames are simply raw RGB images, you can use the [image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) command to display them.

If you require high throughput or need to implement a more complicated decoder, consider implementing it in Java as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1661708/1257977) suggests.