# UDP packet drop issue in Wireshark while wiritng to pcap file

Tags: matlab, udp, wireshark, fpga

My FPGA is continuously sending UDP packets on network using 10/100/1000 Mbps Ethernet. I am using **Wireshark** to capture the packets directly to a .pcap file & then extract & display UDP data in Matlab GUI. FPGA kit is connected to a 1 Gbps switch and then to PC.

Initially i tried using Matlab's built in UDP object instead of .pcap files but using that i was facing packet drop issue at high BW (>1 Mbps) and was only able to achieve drop free reception for very low BW around 110 kbps. That was not acceptable for my case. A link to the problem is given below:

[Incorrect UDP data reception in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645367/incorrect-udp-data-reception-in-matlab?noredirect=1#comment40072089_25645367)

Based on these problems i moved towards using Wireshark. I use wireshark to create multiple .pcap files (1 Mb) of UDP data and then start extracting UDP data from these files in Matlab. A link also guided towards this approach i.e. writing packets directly to file([High speed UDP receiver in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644600/high-speed-udp-receiver-in-matlab)
).

The **problem** is that i am getting some **packets dropped** at random intervals. The problem is very frequent when operating at High Ethernet BW - 220 Mbps. So i reduced my BW to around  <50 Mbps still i get some packet drops. I tried using some of the tips provided by Wireshark (http://wiki.wireshark.org/Performance)  for optimizing performance but still the issue persists.

This seems to be issue with memory as far as i have understood.

Some details about the design:

```
UDP Data Size = 64 Bytes
Ethernet Frame Size = 110 Bytes 
PCAP File Size = 1 Mb
Wireshark Buffer Size = 1 Gb
```

Please guide me towards a possible solution.

Regards,

Sameed

Comment: Some packets could be [fragmented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation) in pcap file. This because pcap file stores not packets, it stores [frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame).

Comment: Ive turned off the fragmentation on these UDP packets. Ive checked by opening the pcap file in Wireshark the packets are indeed missing. Not fragmented.

Comment: Try also dump packets with `tcpdump -n -s 0 -i INTERFACE -w file.pcap`. Also see [this](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/25391/are-there-conditions-that-can-cause-wireshark-to-drop-packets).

Comment: Also to add, in my case Wireshark doesnt show packet dropped??? I always get 100 percent packets probably because i have a buffer size of 1000MB & i write to a file of 1MB.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a larger file size may provide efficiency savings, something like 64MB. Also agree with Slava's suggestion - tcpdump is more efficient/robust than the wireshark GUI.

Comment: HAve checked at larger file size also, the problem was still there

Answer (score -1):

Try writing to a ram disk

[Padding]